# Are Android listeners some kind of a Design Patterns?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

When I work with android I have to use listener for clicks ...etc

such as:

```
Button button = new Button(getActivity());

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do somthing
    }
});
```

However, today I discovered something new for me! I learnt how to create a class that requires listeners from Google's Dialogs | Android Developers API Guide:

```
public static class DatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    interface HijriDatePickerDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);

        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    HijriDatePickerDialogListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mListener = (HijriDatePickerDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement HijriDatePickerDialogListener");
        }

    }
}
```

I want to learn more about this pattern, I want to know what is it called?

Comment: ... this is a surprisingly good question, I think. I just kind of "went with it" and learned how to follow this pattern, but having more info on it would be great. Preferably the pros/cons when compared to EventBus and the like. I know the latter is for "call from anywhere" type of scenarios, and listeners are for constantly called things I believe.

Comment: I would say the Observer pattern is as close as you can get!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a form of the pattern called the Observer pattern. You can learn more about the Observer pattern here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

A great explanation of design patterns is given in this book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns (typically called 'Gang of Four' book on Design Patterns).

Comment: this is a comment! only proving two links is no answer... see my comment on the question above.

Comment: So, as mentioned in my above comment, this pattern applies to both these types of interfaces as well as EventBus, correct?

Comment: @kentarosu Yes, the register/subscribe and then notify is a form of the observer pattern as well.

Comment: @haywire My apologies, I didn't see your comment before I posted my answer. I'm not sure that it doesn't qualify as a valid answer to the question, though, as it is, in fact, the correct answer to the question the OP was asking.

Comment: I found that iOS (with Swift) also uses exact pattern but in a different name, they called it "delegate".

Comment: I feel its strategy pattern , My question related to the same is : https://stackoverflow.com/q/54855594/504133

Answer (score 3):

The first example of your code is an event listener / observer but don't confuse it with the second.

As for the second, I'm not sure where you got the code from but whoever wrote it is confusing the issue by referring to what is a 'callback' interface by using the word 'listener'. Just because it has the word "Listener" in it doesn't mean it's the same as the usual event listeners in Android.

What you're dealing with in your second example is a 'callback' interface designed to be used with any `Activity` your `Fragment` is attached to.

Taking that code and adjusting it you could simply do the following as the 'callback' interface methods would be called directly in your code...

```
public static class DatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    interface HijriDatePickerDialogCallbacks {
        public void dialogPositiveHasBeenClicked(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void dialogNegativeHasBeenClicked(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    HijriDatePickerDialogCallback mCallbacks;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallbacks = (HijriDatePickerDialogCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement HijriDatePickerDialogCallbacks");
        }

    }
}
```

Using a 'callbacks' interface is a standard design pattern for Android when using `Fragments` which need to communicate with the `Activity` they're attached to.

Notice I removed the term "listener" from your code and substituted "callbacks" instead. When your `Activity` creates the `Fragment` the `Fragment` assigns a reference to `mCallBacks` and is able to communicate directly with the `Activity` through the callback methods implemented by the `Activity`.

Comment: what's the reason for posting exactly the same code of the OP again?

Comment: It's not just limited to Activities and Fragments, though.

Comment: @haywire : I didn't post the exact code - I modified it to remove the term "listener". Callbacks when defined as an interface for `Fragment` -> `Activity` communication are a standard Android design pattern. I was trying to illustrate the point that a callbacks interface isn't a "listener" / observer and the interface can be named anything (but conventionally it would contain the word 'callbacks' rather than 'listener').

Comment: @Squonk ok, i see what you did there.

Comment: @kentarosu : Agreed. Callback interfaces can be used in many ways but in this case the OP is using a class which extends `DialogFragment` and attaching it to an `Activity`.

Comment: @Squonk I think you wrote up a great answer, but I'm a little bit skeptical of the arbitrary distinction you create between Observers/Listeners and Callbacks. I know that in Ruby on Rails, Callbacks and Observers are classified slightly differently to adhere to separation of concerns, but I think in Android (i.e. Java), the distinction is somewhat less necessary. That said, you could make an argument for why the two are separately named, which would make your answer a bit more informational for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are kind of Observer pattern, or a specialization of this pattern.. However i found in a blog about Android-useful design patterns and they are mentioning [Adapter Pattern](http://minhazr.blogspot.com/2013/10/design-pattern-every-android-developer.html) as a separate thing.