# Is using OnClickListener() an example of Strategy pattern?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Is [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) in android an example of Strategy pattern ? In another Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512835/are-android-listeners-some-kind-of-a-design-patterns) accepted answer says it is Observer Pattern.

Similar Code to understand the question.

```
public interface OnClickListener{
    void onClick(View view);
}

public class Button extends View{
    private OnClickListener listener;
    void clicked(){
        //some code
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onClick(this);
        }
        //some other code
    }
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

My reasoning to believe its strategy pattern and not observer pattern :

1. Here we see `Button` class does not has a list of listeners(Observers) but can have only one listener.
2. It delegates a part of method to its instance member : listener at a time.
3. `OnClickListener` is similar to a strategy where user code implements an strategy (method) to be invoked once button is clicked.
4. Different implementations of `OnClickListener` can be passed to `Button` object during run time and behavior can be changed during run time. (Same button upon clicked may show a pop up with one implementation of `OnClickListener` and may send a request to server if another implementation of `OnClickListener` is passed.)

Comment: Why not a simple callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the intent of the Observer Pattern from page 293.

> Define a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object
>   changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

Strictly speaking, the code example is not an Observer then, because the one-to-many relationship is rather one-to-one. However, I would not call this a Strategy either, per its intent from page 315.

> Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable.
>   Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

Semantically, a listener is not an algorithm; i.e. responding to an event is a different purpose from performing a calculation. This purpose manifests syntactically where the `onClick()` method is `void` and therefore behaves more like a listener.

For that reason, I would call the code example a *degenerate* form of the Observer Pattern. It looks to me like an Observer attempt that didn't quite meet the qualifications. I wouldn't dignify the attempt by associating it with another pattern.

Comment: Hmm so is it like strategy pattern is related to only algorithmic based methods ? Any method is usually invoked due to occurrence of some or the other event (apart from some scheduled method invocations at fixed interval by some background thread). We could have an application where some algorithm runs on click of button may be some kind of  image processing which can have multiple implementations. Still would we categorize it as a pattern similar to Observer.

Comment: The Strategy Pattern is an OO workaround for languages that lack first-class functions. In a language with lambdas or closures, the pattern is replaced by those. From Strategy to Observer, the difference between calling a function and triggering a side effect is a shift between programming paradigms. I'm confident that most design pattern aficionados would identify this code as Observer, if only because of the method and variable names; but to me, the return type of `onClick()` is more important. Regardless, my strict interpretation is that there is no GoF design pattern here.